# How do I install the latest version of gcc(13.2.0) in a dev container with image suse/sle15:15.2?

Tags: c++, docker, containers, suse

I am trying to run a c++ program on a dev container(docker container). I have attached VS code to that container. The docker container is running SUSE SLES15 SP2.
(image: registry.suse.com/suse/sle15:15.2)
This is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
    // Print "Hello, World!"
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    // Example filesystem operations
    std::filesystem::path currentPath = std::filesystem::current_path();
    std::cout << "Current path: " << currentPath << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

A fairly simple program that uses the std cpp 17 library filesystem

But now the gcc complains that there is no such file or directory.

```
/home/developer/workspace/rough # g++ hello.cpp
hello.cpp:2:10: fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
 #include <filesystem>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

When I check the gcc --version it says

```
/home/developer/workspace/rough # gcc --version
gcc (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Now I do know that the gcc version is an older version and hence the filesystem does not exist. (I also do not want to use experimental/filesystem)

How do I update the gcc version in this case?

I have tried the following:
I have tried to update gcc version by running zypper update. But this does not update the gcc version.

I tried to install the latest version of gcc using homebrew. I was able to download the latest version but after I add the PATH to the latest gcc in .bashrc, It would still point to 7.5.0. How do I update this?

Comment: You should add `-std=c++17` (or higher) to your compile command line if you are using a c++ 17 feature. Won't help in this case, but could still be an issue with a newer compiler if the default is lower.

Comment: You need to update the installed GCC, which isn't specific to Docker but a general admin task. This is effectively not about programming, so check out e.g. superuser.com instead.

Comment: Do you have your image's Dockerfile or any other reproduction information?  My suspicion reading this is that the gcc/g++ version is just fine, but you're missing the header files for the standard library.

Comment: @DavidMaze, Pfb the dockerfile:
FROM registry.suse.com/suse/sle15:15.2
RUN zypper --gpg-auto-import-keys ref
RUN zypper up -y
RUN zypper in --allow-downgrade -y -t pattern devel_basis 
RUN zypper in -y gcc-c++ wget curl jq sudo

Answer (score 0):

I don't have license for SUSE but you can do this with a recent version of OpenSUSE.

```
FROM opensuse/tumbleweed

RUN zypper update -y && \
    zypper install -y gcc-c++

COPY hello.cpp .

RUN g++ hello.cpp -o hello

CMD ./hello
```

[image]